# How to rewrite URL paths in Apache to avoid infinite loop

Tags: apache, url, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm trying to set some rewrites rules on my VirtualHost. I try to redirect root '/' to a specific path '/mypath'. An a path '/foo' to root '/' without enter in a loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} =server.domain.com/foo
RewriteRule /foo / [R,E=DEV:true]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =server.domain.com
RewriteCond %{ENV:DEV} !^true$
RewriteRule ^/$ /mypath [R]
```

I'm expecting that if the user ask for:

`server.domain.com/foo` he/she goes to `server.domain.com`

And if the user ask for:

`server.domain.com` he/she goes to `server.domain.com/mypath`

As you could see on my code I set an environmental variable to check If I have to rewrite or not, but isn't working.

Comment: You are doing an external redirect, the environment variable doesn’t “survive” that - new request, new environment variables. // What you want does not make much sense to begin with - HTTP is a stateless protocol, so there is no difference between the request for `server.domain.com`, that you made the client request via a redirect, and a client requesting `server.domain.com` directly to begin with.

Comment: You would have to create a way for the server to differentiate between the two somehow in the first place (check a referrer, _if_ it exists, or introduce a cookie – but then you’re still in trouble if the client rejects those.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved using two domains.

We create:
`server.domain.com` and `server-aux.domain.com`

The rewrite rules looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^server-aux.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server.domain.com/foo [R=301]
```

Now `server.domain.com` goes to `/` and `server-aux.domain.com` goes to `/foo`